# When playing random 2v2, can you be paired with a pre-arranged team?

Tags: starcraft-2

When you're playing "random 2v2" (random partner, not race), can you be paired against a team of two players that are in a pre-arranged team and not randomly assigned?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. I have played many games as a prearranged team and we have been paired vs people who know each other as well as people who do not.

Comment: yes, and it's annoying because they often have a developed strategy, so even "Even Match" matchups can be a mess :)

Comment: side-note: if it wasn't so, you could end up in a paradox where pre-arranged teams had longer queues than random teams, which is quite plainly a bad thing.

Comment: @tenfour Who is favored is based entirely on MMR, so you should win about 50% of the time vs any prearranged team that you are an "Even Match" with. It is really just the nature of 2v2 where sometimes the strength of one team or the strategy they use will exploit the weakness of the other team's strategy and turn it into a one-sided slaughter.

Comment: True. Maybe I'm just bitter because of my recent loss-streak :D

Comment: @en1gmatic325: Random teams can use *strategy*??

Comment: @Wikwocket Well, some of them can at least. Your results may vary :-P

Answer (score 4):

I believe so, as I've played against people that were randomly assigned to each other in my 2v2 matches (where my team was with a friend).